# FAB above BaiduMap MapView is visible but not touchable

Tags: android, xml, android-mapview, visible, floating-action-button

I'm using Baidu Map Android SDK because I'm in China. I want to put a Float Action Button above the MapView (the effect pic is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt7nz.png)). But when I do this normally, the FAB is **visible but not touchable**. **It seems that there's another touch layer of the map view on top of the FAB that cut off my touch.**

What makes me even more surprised is, if I change the FAB into a common Button, it works fine when clicked.

Part of my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.baidu.mapapi.map.TextureMapView
        android:id="@+id/bmapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/get_current_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy way to handle this:

**Add `android:clickable="true"` to the FAB.**

Though I don't know why it is necessary.